# Error 1064 en create table

Tags: php, mysql

> (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, nomCognoms varchar(60) not NULL unique_key, adreca va' at line 2

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE aligxager 
(id INT(11) not NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
nomCognoms varchar(60) not NULL unique_key, 
adreca varchar(50) not NULL, 
ciutat varchar(50) not NULL, 
cp varchar(50) not NULL, 
comarcaPais varchar(50) not NULL, 
dataNaix varchar(20) not NULL, 
adrecaE varchar(255) not NULL, 
periode INT(1) not NULL, 
dataPagament INT(1) not NULL, 
esMembre INT(1) not NULL, 
volBanquet INT(1) not NULL, 
volPlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
volcotxePlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
TotalPagar INT(11) not NULL, 
tipusAllotjament INT(1) not NULL, 
modePagament INT(1) not NULL, 
comentaris blob, 
anyCongres int (11), 
donaco varchar (10),
PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

Comment: Es posible que de mas informacion al respecto?

Comment: Es decir, porque le aparece ese error? En donde le aparece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error de sintaxis me parece que puede ser por esto(unique_key):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE aligxager 
(id INT(11) not NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
nomCognoms varchar(60) not NULL unique_key, //Cambialo por UNIQUE
adreca varchar(50) not NULL, 
ciutat varchar(50) not NULL, 
cp varchar(50) not NULL, 
comarcaPais varchar(50) not NULL, 
dataNaix varchar(20) not NULL, 
adrecaE varchar(255) not NULL, 
periode INT(1) not NULL, 
dataPagament INT(1) not NULL, 
esMembre INT(1) not NULL, 
volBanquet INT(1) not NULL, 
volPlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
volcotxePlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
TotalPagar INT(11) not NULL, 
tipusAllotjament INT(1) not NULL, 
modePagament INT(1) not NULL, 
comentaris blob, 
anyCongres int (11), 
donaco varchar (10),
PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

Asi quedaria:

```
nomCognoms varchar(60) not NULL UNIQUE,
```

y si no, prueba quitando el UNSIGNED como es auto_increment no hace falta esa sentencia ya que mysql inicia desde 1:

```
(id INT(11) not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: Gracias a todos, pero principalmente a Francisco Veracoechea: 1º he probado con el "not null unique" y ha dado el mismo error y 2º al quitar "unsigned", me ha creado la tabla. Muchísimas gracias; llevaba toda la semana probando, aprendiendo, etc. Ahora tengo 72 años pero havia aprendido SQL en el 1985 en un sistema IBM 4385 y trabajé hasta mediados de los 90 haciendo bastantes "virguerias". Ahora hace más de 20 años que no havia hecho nada con SQL. Estoy feliz por tu ayuda. Ah!, lo que estoy haciendo es para una asociación cultural. Saludos.

Comment: Que bueno  que lo solucionaste, para eso estamos.. saludos!!.

Answer (score 1):

ESTO FUNCIONA (lo he elaborado y testado en mi localhost)

Puedes hacerlo con 2 queries. Primero creamos la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE aligxager 
(`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nomCognoms varchar(60) not NULL, 
adreca varchar(50) not NULL, 
ciutat varchar(50) not NULL, 
cp varchar(50) not NULL, 
comarcaPais varchar(50) not NULL, 
dataNaix varchar(20) not NULL, 
adrecaE varchar(255) not NULL, 
periode INT(1) not NULL, 
dataPagament INT(1) not NULL, 
esMembre INT(1) not NULL, 
volBanquet INT(1) not NULL, 
volPlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
volcotxePlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
TotalPagar INT(11) not NULL, 
tipusAllotjament INT(1) not NULL, 
modePagament INT(1) not NULL, 
comentaris blob, 
anyCongres int (11), 
donaco varchar (10),
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Y posteriormente añadimos Unique key al nomCognoms:

```
ALTER TABLE `aligxager` ADD UNIQUE (`nomCognoms`);
```

**TODO EN UNO:**

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE aligxager 
(`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nomCognoms varchar(60) not NULL, 
adreca varchar(50) not NULL, 
ciutat varchar(50) not NULL, 
cp varchar(50) not NULL, 
comarcaPais varchar(50) not NULL, 
dataNaix varchar(20) not NULL, 
adrecaE varchar(255) not NULL, 
periode INT(1) not NULL, 
dataPagament INT(1) not NULL, 
esMembre INT(1) not NULL, 
volBanquet INT(1) not NULL, 
volPlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
volcotxePlanetari  INT(1) not NULL, 
TotalPagar INT(11) not NULL, 
tipusAllotjament INT(1) not NULL, 
modePagament INT(1) not NULL, 
comentaris blob, 
anyCongres int (11), 
donaco varchar (10),
PRIMARY KEY (id));
ALTER TABLE `aligxager` ADD UNIQUE (`nomCognoms`);
";
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con esto:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE aligxager (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nomCognoms varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  adreca varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  ciutat varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  cp varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  comarcaPais varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  dataNaix varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  adrecaE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  periode int(1) NOT NULL,
  dataPagament int(1) NOT NULL,
  esMembre int(1) NOT NULL,
  volBanquet int(1) NOT NULL,
  volPlanetari int(1) NOT NULL,
  volcotxePlanetari int(1) NOT NULL,
  TotalPagar int(11) NOT NULL,
  tipusAllotjament int(1) NOT NULL,
  modePagament int(1) NOT NULL,
  comentaris blob,
  anyCongres int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  donaco varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY un_nomCognoms_aligxager (nomCognoms)
)"
```